# eps parser that can fail for a "post-initialization" that could fail

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, c++14, boost-spirit-x3

I'm reading [the Boost X3 Quick Start tutorial](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/tutorials/roman_numerals.html) and noticed the line

> `eps` is a special spirit parser that consumes no input but is always successful. We use it to initialize the rule's synthesized attribute, to zero before anything else. [...] Using `eps` this way is good for doing pre and post initializations.

Now I can't help but wonder if an `eps_that_might_fail` would be useful to do some sort of semantic/post analysis on a part of the parsed input, which could fail, to have some sort of locality of the check inside the grammar.

Is there a might-fail `eps`, and is it a good idea to do extra input verification using this construct?

A terrible example of what I'm trying to convey:

```
int_ >> eps_might_fail[is_prime]
```

This will only parse prime numbers, if I'm not mistaken, and allow for the full parser to fail at the point where it expects a prime number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantic actions are intended for this.

## Spirit Qi

The most natural example would be

```
 qi::int_ [ qi::_pass = is_prime(qi::_1) ]
```

Be sure to use `%=` rule assignment in the presence of semantic actions, because without it, semantic actions disable automatic attribute propagation.

You could, obviously, also be more verbose, and write

```
 qi::int_ >> qi::eps(is_prime(qi::_val))
```

As you can see, that quoted documentation is slightly incomplete: `eps` can already take a parameter, in this case the lazy actor `is_prime(qi::_val)`, that determines whether it succeeds of fails.

## Spirit X3

In Spirit X3 the same mechanism applies, except that X3 doesn't integrate with Phoenix. This means two things:

- on the up-side, we can just use core language features (lambdas) for semantic actions, making the learning curve less steep
- on the downside, there's no 1-argument version of `x3::eps` that takes a lazy actor

Here's a demo program with X3:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7281f5ec19b6190)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto is_ltua = [](auto& ctx) {
        _pass(ctx) = 0 == (_attr(ctx) % 42); 
    };

    auto start = int_ [ is_ltua ];

}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (std::string const txt : { "43", "42", "84", "85" }) {
        int data;
        if (parse(txt.begin(), txt.end(), parser::start, data))
            std::cout << "Parsed " << data << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed (" << txt << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parse failed (43)
Parsed 42
Parsed 84
Parse failed (85)
```

Comment: Ouch I noticed X3 late. It's no doubt similar let met try.

Comment: Extended the answer with X3 demo, difference and rationales! [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7281f5ec19b6190)

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks :). I find it hard to find good resources on X3 (there seem to be none except the cppnow2015 slides and documentation...). So thanks for being a valuable resource :D.